# How do I filter and sync an object array accross multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm currently working on an angular app in which I have a service returning data from a $http request.

To reduce http requests, I'm storing a large amount of data ( 100-300 )  results per search.

I have three Controllers:

1. holds my filters (sliders, checkboxes etc)
2. holds my list of items
3. holds a google map which shows the markers of all the returned results.

Im trying to filter the array in controller one and update this accross for controller two and three. So ideally all three controllers are watching and using the same array.

Can anyone help, is this even possible ?

Comment: Have a look at services in Angular. Unlike $scope, services are singletons and therefore are the same across al controllers/scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your array in the $rootScope
This is a global scope that can be accessed from all others controllers.

```
angular.module('App').controller('OneController', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope',  function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.propertiesForThisScope = 123;
    $rootScope.theArray = [];
}]);
```